# Redis query with wildcard for Hash

Tags: redis, ft.search

I have redis hashes as below.

HSET post:33 postId 33 title "Sumit Title 33"
HSET post:334 postId 334 title "Sumit Title 334" 
HSET post:334 postId 22 title "Sumit Title 22"

It had an index like below -
FT.CREATE idx ON HASH PREFIX 1 "post:" SCHEMA postId TEXT SORTABLE title TEXT SORTABLE

Can you do a wildcard search like find all document with postId staring with '3' .. FT.SEARCH idx "@postId:3*" ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you index the post ID as text you can look for a prefix, and from version 2.6 for suffix, infix or wildcard matching.

You can read more on this syntax [in the documentation](https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/reference/query_syntax/).

Notice that there is a limit to the number of required characters before a prefix. From the documentations:

> Prefixes are limited to 2 letters or more. You can change this number by using the `MINPREFIX` setting on the module command line.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the dafault as 2 :)